# Step size to use in ode solver - python

Tags: python, ode

I am using the `ode` solver from `scipy.integrate` to solve my differential equation. I wanted to see whether the final result was affected by the choice of the step-size in the integration `dt`, and this is what I get:

[image]

I would expect the result to be correct for *any* small integration step-size, but I see almost the opposite... does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

--

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y0, t0 = 0., 0

def f2(t, y, arg1):
    t0 = 5
    shape = np.piecewise(t, [t<t0, t>=t0], [arg1*t, arg1*(2*t0-t)])
    return shape

t1 = 10.
dtlist = np.array([t1/j for j in range(1, 50)])
temp = []

for i in dtlist:
    dt = i
    r = ode(f2).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf')
    r.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(2.0)   

    while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
        r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    temp.append(r.y)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
xaxis = dtlist
yaxis = temp
axs.plot(xaxis, yaxis, 'bo', label = 'obtained')
axs.plot(xaxis, xaxis - xaxis + 50, 'r--', label = 'expected')
axs.set_xlabel('time increment $\delta t$')
axs.set_ylabel('Final $y$ value')
axs.legend(loc = 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the last integration step always ends at `t1`. Due to floating point errors it may happen that the desired last integration step goes to `r.t` slightly less than `t1` so that an additional unwanted step to about `t1+dt` is performed. You could use

```
r.integrate(min(r.t+dt, t1))
```

to cut off the integration at the right time. Or do something more involved to catch the case where `r.t+dt` is already close to `t1`.